# pointer dereference: actual mechanism of compiler

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm struggling a little bit with my understanding concerning the actual mechanism in dereferencing pointers (what the compiler actually does).

I red a lot through google and on here on stackoverflow, but I coulnd't quite get it yet :-(

I wrote a simple program with multiple pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int* ptr = &a;
    int** pptr = &ptr;
    int*** ppptr = &pptr;
    int**** p4tr = &ppptr;

    std::cout << "a = 5 \nint*ptr = &a \nint** pptr = *ptr\nint*** ppptr = &pptr\nint**** p4tr= &ppptr\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&a: " << &a << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ptr: " << ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*ptr: " << *ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&ptr: " << &ptr << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pptr: " << pptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*ptr: " << *pptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "**pptr: "<< **pptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&pptr: " << &pptr << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ppptr: " << ppptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*ppptr: " << *ppptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "**pptr: " << **ppptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "***pptr: " << ***ppptr << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "&pptr: " << &ppptr << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p4tr: " << p4tr<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "*p4tr: " << *p4tr<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "**p4tr: " << **p4tr<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "***p4tr: " << ***p4tr<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "****p4tr: " << ****p4tr<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "&p4tr: " << &p4tr<< std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives me this on my machine:

```
a = 5 
int*ptr = &a 
int** pptr = *ptr
int*** ppptr = &pptr
int**** p4tr= &ppptr

a: 5
&a: 0x7fffe4db870c

ptr: 0x7fffe4db870c
*ptr: 5
&ptr: 0x7fffe4db8700

pptr: 0x7fffe4db8700
*ptr: 0x7fffe4db870c
**pptr: 5
&pptr: 0x7fffe4db86f8

ppptr: 0x7fffe4db86f8
*ppptr: 0x7fffe4db8700
**pptr: 0x7fffe4db870c
***pptr: 5
&pptr: 0x7fffe4db86f0

p4tr: 0x7fffe4db86f0
*p4tr: 0x7fffe4db86f8
**p4tr: 0x7fffe4db8700
***p4tr: 0x7fffe4db870c
****p4tr: 5
&p4tr: 0x7fffe4db86e8
```

What I figured out, how dereference works is:
int* ptr = &a; tells the compiler that the "variable" ptr is of type "int*" (pointer to an interger; i.e. memory address)
Hence, when I write *ptr, the compiler takes the value of ptr, takes it as an address and interpretes what is stored at the very address as type int.

So far, so good.

But what does int** pptr = &ptr actually mean to the compiler ?
Does it mean pptr is of type " int** " ?
or does it still mean pptr is of type " int* " (i mean, &ptr is as good a memory address as &a)

What does the second asterix actually mean to the compiler and why can't I write: "int* pptr = &ptr"
(at least g++ won't let me do that)

thank you so much for your efforts,
it hurts my brain, if things seem unlogical to me :-))

Comment: "it hurts my brain" - don't worry. This hurts even the most experienced C++ gurus' brains. Don't try to be a [three-star programmer.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: A pointer is just an address. You can take someone's address and write it down on a piece of paper. And then you can write down where you left the paper on another piece of paper.

Comment: @H2CO3  "three-star-programmer"...this made my day (night) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what does `int** pptr = &ptr` actually mean to the compiler? Does it mean pptr is of type `int**`?

Yes, `pptr` is of type `int**`. And `int**` is *pointer to pointer to int*. So `*pptr` has type `int*`, and `**pptr` has type `int`.

> Why can't I write: `int* pptr = &ptr`?

Well, `ptr` has type `int*`. And so `&ptr` has type `int**` which is not assignment compatible with a variable of type `int*`. A *pointer to int* is a different type of thing to a *pointer to pointer to int*.

Comment: Ok. This seems logical. I am still a little bit confused, because this book* says "int*" is just a type used to tell the compiler that the following number is an address (like "char" is used to tell the compiler its a letter). Is the book wrong ? Because int** would contradict this book' definition, wouldn't it ?                * This is the very text passage: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=Ehnbg

Comment: `int*` is a pointer to `int`. `int**` is a pointer to `int*`. `int***` is a pointer to `int**`. And so on. I'm not really sure what you regard as contradictory.

Comment: Whoos..the text got tangled up a little. Here's the actual version: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=7zLWy

Comment: I still don't see any contradiction.

Comment: Fore example

    int main()
    {
    int* p = (int*) 0x7fff05270198;

    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
    }                       
So I assigned this int* value directly to p. How could I assign a int** value directly to p ?

Comment: `0x7fff05270198` is not an `int**`. It is a integral value. You cannot assign it to a pointer directly. You had to cast.

Comment: hahaha...omg..ok...i got it. int** p = (int**) 0x....thanks david. I think i just play around with it a little bit more now